# How do you increment with biwascheme?

Tags: scheme, sicp

Has anyone used the online ide replit? http://repl.it/languages/Scheme

How do you increment with it?

I'm trying to encapsulate a function to sum things up based on sicp video 2a.

```
(define (square a ) 
    (* a a))


(define (sum term a next b)
    (if (> a b)
        0
        (+ (term a) 
            (sum term (next a ) next b))))

(define (sum-int a b)
    (define (identity a) a)
    (sum identity a (+ 1 a) b))


(define (sum-square a b)
    (sum square a (+1 ) b))

    (sum-square 1 2)
```

alternate sum-square (not working)

```
(define (sum-square a b)
    (sum square a (+ 1  a) b))

    (sum-square 1 2)  // getting 2 not a function.
```

Working code:

```
(define (sum-int a b)
    (define (identity a) a)
    (sum identity a (lambda(a)(+ 1 a)) b))
```

Comment: I haven't finished learning scheme yet, but don't you need `lambda` if you want a function returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a *function* as the `next` parameter, like this:

```
(define (identity n) n)

(define (sum-int a b)
  (sum identity a add1 b))

(define (sum-square a b)
  (sum square a add1 b))
```

In case `add1` isn't defined, you can write your own version:

```
(define (add1 n)
    (+ 1 n))
```

Alternatively, you can directly pass a `lambda`:

```
(define (sum-int a b)
  (sum identity a (lambda (n) (+ 1 n)) b))

(define (sum-square a b)
  (sum square a (lambda (n) (+ 1 n)) b))
```